# Is it possible to prevent users from cloning a branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a self hosted instance of Gitlab CE, and are wondering whether or not it is possible to prevent users from cloning a given branch.

Having looked into this, my strong suspicion is that it isn't possible. But my questions are:

1. Does gitlab allow you to control whether branches can be cloned?
2. Is there any kind of git hosting which allows you to control whether branches can be cloned?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think gitlab can prevent from cloning a branch but it can prevent from pushing a specific branch users can do anything with it locally but can't push I dont really get why you dont want some users to Clone the branch

Comment: Nobody can clone any branch, you can only clone a *repository* and then checkout a branch. So be more precise in what you want to allow, and what you want to prevent. Maybe if you explain the purpose, things would be clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the input - thinking about it, no git hosting would prevent checking out a branch, because as you say, you always clone the whole repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot protect a branch from "cloning" - you always clone an entire repository.

- You can make the project private so people don't see your project.
- You can protect branches from pushing.